# Как создать svg-градиент с 3 точками в треугольнике, которые смешиваются вместе

Tags: html, css, svg, градиент, svg-animation

```html
<svg id="color-gradient" width="400" height="400" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="blue" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Я хочу создать svg-градиент в круге с 3 цветными зонами, в виде треугольников.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<svg id="color-gradient" width="400" height="400" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="blue" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Я попытался создать линейный градиент с тремя `stops`, но я не уверен, как расположить `stops` там, где они мне нужны (вверху слева направо).

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56701484/7394871

Answer (score 4):

### В качестве бонуса добавлены примеры анимации

1. Вращение градиента

Добавляется команда анимации группы элементов `id="gr1"` :

```
circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="white" stroke="silver">
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" xlink:href="#gr1" dur="2s" values="0 50 50;360   50 50" repeatcount="indefinite"/>
   </circle>
```

Полный код:

```html
<style>
svg {
  width: 400px;
}
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur" color-interpolation-filters="linear" x="-25%" y="-25%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="7"/>
    </filter> 
    <mask id="circle">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="white">
   
    </circle>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g id="gr1" mask="url(#circle)" filter="url(#blur)">
    <rect x="-10" width="110" height="110" fill="blue"/>
    <rect x="50" width="60" height="110" fill="yellow"/>
    <polygon points="50,50, 60,110, 40,110" fill="#0f8"/>
    <polygon points="0,0, 100,0, 100,20, 50,50, 0,20" fill="red"/>
    <polygon points="0,10, 50,50, 0,30" fill="#f0f"/>
    <polygon points="100,10, 100,30, 50,50" fill="#f80"/>
  </g>
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="white" stroke="silver">
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" xlink:href="#gr1" dur="2s" values="0 50 50;360   50 50" repeatcount="indefinite"/>
   </circle>  
   
   </svg>
```

**2. Анимация дорожек**

Добавляется команда анимации радиуса окружностей

```
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="none" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="gray" >
     <animate id="an1" attributeName="r" values="5;50" dur="2s" begin="0s" repeatcount="indefinite" />
    </circle>
```

```html
<style>
svg {
  width: 400px;
}
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur" color-interpolation-filters="linear" x="-25%" y="-25%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="7"/>
    </filter> 
    <mask id="circle">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="white">
     </circle>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g id="gr1" mask="url(#circle)" filter="url(#blur)">
    <rect x="-10" width="110" height="110" fill="blue"/>
    <rect x="50" width="60" height="110" fill="yellow"/>
    <polygon points="50,50, 60,110, 40,110" fill="#0f8"/>
    <polygon points="0,0, 100,0, 100,20, 50,50, 0,20" fill="red"/>
    <polygon points="0,10, 50,50, 0,30" fill="#f0f"/>
    <polygon points="100,10, 100,30, 50,50" fill="#f80"/>
  </g>
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="white" stroke="silver">
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" xlink:href="#gr1" dur="2s" values="0 50 50;360   50 50" repeatcount="indefinite"/>
   </circle>  
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="none" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="gray" >
     <animate id="an1" attributeName="r" values="5;50" dur="2s" begin="0s" repeatcount="indefinite" />
 </circle> 
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="none" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="gray" >
     <animate id="an2" attributeName="r" values="5;50" dur="2s" begin="0.5s" repeatcount="indefinite" />
   </circle> 
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="none" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="gray" >
     <animate id="an3" attributeName="r" values="5;50" dur="2s" begin="1s" repeatcount="indefinite" />
   </circle> 
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="none" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="gray" >
     <animate id="an3" attributeName="r" values="5;50" dur="2s" begin="1.5s" repeatcount="indefinite" />
   </circle> 
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="none" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="gray" >
     <animate id="an3" attributeName="r" values="5;50" dur="2s" begin="2s" repeatcount="indefinite" />
   </circle>  
   </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

В примере ниже близко, то, что вы хотите получить.

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur" color-interpolation-filters="linear" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="9"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="circle">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#circle)" filter="url(#blur)">
    <rect x="-10" width="110" height="110" fill="blue"/>
    <rect x="50" width="60" height="110" fill="yellow"/>
    <polygon points="50,50, 60,110, 40,110" fill="#0f8"/>
    <polygon points="0,0, 100,0, 100,20, 50,50, 0,20" fill="red"/>
    <polygon points="0,10, 50,50, 0,30" fill="#f0f"/>
    <polygon points="100,10, 100,30, 50,50" fill="#f80"/>
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

Поскольку смешивание, которое вы получаете в CSS / SVG, работает исключительно путем отдельного сочетания красного, зеленого и синего каналов цветов RGB, то он не знает, что мы ожидаем увидеть зеленый, когда мы смешиваем синий и желтый. Вместо этого вы получите мутный серый.

Таким образом, в приведенном выше примере я «обманул», добавив полоски «правильных» цветов между нашими тремя основными цветами. Например, я положил полоску зеленого цвета между синим и желтым секторами.

**Если я этого не сделаю, приведенный выше пример будет выглядеть так:**

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur" color-interpolation-filters="linear" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="7"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="circle">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#circle)" filter="url(#blur)">
    <rect x="-10" width="110" height="110" fill="blue"/>
    <rect x="50" width="60" height="110" fill="yellow"/>
    <polygon points="0,0, 100,0, 100,20, 50,50, 0,20" fill="red"/>
  </g>
  
</svg>
```